# String manipulation VBA

Tags: string, vba

I am stuck on a very simple problem. I have the following string:

```
Dim s as String
s = "031, 603-604, 803-804, 617, 817, 619, 819, 621, 821, 627, 827, 629, 829, 831, 645-646, 845-846, 647-648, 847-848, 649-650, 849-850, 667-668, 867-868, 671-672, 871-872, 677-678, 675-676, 875-876, 679-680"
```

Now I want to separate the codes into an array, so I have a loop going char by char (concatting up), if the char is either "," or "-", return the code and reset the concatting.

```
For i = 1 To Len(s)
    If Not ((Mid(s, i, 1) = ",") Or (Mid(s, i, 1) = " ") Or (Mid(s, i, 1) = "-")) Then
        code = code & Mid(s, i, 1)
     ElseIf (Mid(s, i, 1) = ",") Or (Mid(s, i, 1) = "-") Then
        Debug.Print code
        code = ""
     End If
Next i
```

Instead of getting 031, 603, 604... I get 031, 603-604... Basically the loop ignores the `(Mid(s, i, 1) = "-")` part, but accepts `(Mid(s, i, 1) = ",")` as a condition to reset the code value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make it a lot more easier if you used some String manipulation functions like so,

```
Dim s as String, tmpArr() As String

s = "031, 603-604, 803-804, 617, 817, 619, 819, 621, 821, 627, 827, 629, 829, 831, " & _
    "645-646, 845-846, 647-648, 847-848, 649-650, 849-850, 667-668, 867-868, 671-672, " & _
    "871-872, 677-678, 675-676, 875-876, 679-680"

s = Replace(Replace(s, "-", ","), " ", "")

tmpArr = Split(s, ",")
```

Now **tmpArr** contains an Array of Strings that will be just 031, 603, 604.... etc. To verify you can use

```
Dim iCtr As Long
For iCtr = 0 To UBound(tmpArr)
    Debug.Print tmpArr(iCtr)
Next
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that makes sense. How would I go about creating a function for this specific task (which returns the array)? Public Function code(s as String) as String; s =  Replace(Replace(s, "-", ","), " ", ""); code = Split(s, ","); End Function; This returns a Compile Error: Expected array when I try to run it as tmpArr = code(s). I get what the error means, but I don't get how should I correct it. I assume it has to do with the declaration of the function itself.

Comment: What is Code? Why are you using Code(s) and assigning it to tmpArr? It would be great if you could open up a **new thread** as code in comment is very confusing and it is not clear what you are intending to do.